# I am getting space between jquery mobile menus

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Why I am getting space between listview menu

[image]

Here is my code

```
<script id="panel-init">
    $( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
        $( "body > [data-role='panel']" ).panel();
        $( "body > [data-role='panel'] [data-role='listview']" ).listview();
    });
    $( document ).one( "pageshow", function() {
        $( "body > [data-role='header']" ).toolbar();
        $( "body > [data-role='header'] [data-role='navbar']" ).navbar();
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>Order</h3>
        <a class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-back" data-rel="back"></a>
        <a class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-bars" href="#rightPanel"></a>
      </div>
```

Here is the external panel defined out of `page`

```
<!-- Right panel-->
    <div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="push" data-theme="b" id="rightPanel">
<ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
    </div><!-- /rightPanel -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to initialize the header and panel once on document ready, not on pagecreate or pageshow:

```
$(function() {
    $( "body > [data-role='panel']" ).panel();
    $( "body > [data-role='panel'] [data-role='listview']" ).listview();

    $( "[data-role='navbar']" ).navbar();
    $( "[data-role='header']" ).toolbar();
});
```

Other than that your code works:

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3fzmfob6/)**

Note: if you copied the listview markup from the jQM dem site, you might have ended up with extra `&nbsp;` characters instead of regular spaces in the markip. Try erasing all spaces between the `<LI>` elements in the source page, and see if the problem goes away.